# Devise not respecting config.email_regexp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I wanted to change the regex that defines valid emails in my application. I am trying to do this in config/initializers/devise.rb. To check whether the regex was working I tried to start with something easy like

```
config.email_regexp = /\d+/
```

when that didn't work, I thought maybe my knowledge of ruby's regex sytax was off and tried what I thought was a super simple regex

```
config.email_regexp = /a/
```

While changing the following DOES have an impact on the passwords allowed, the previous two lines seem to have no effect.

```
config.password_length = 2..128
```

What else should I do in order to modify the regex validating emails? (after I made each of these modifications I restarted the server to make sure the changes were picked up.)

Answer (score 0):

You realize what those regex's match right?

/\d+/ matches one or more digits, and /a/ matches a single 'a'. This would make just about every email address invalid, no?

Check out this site to test your regexes and see if that helps:

http://rubular.com/

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, but I do understand that those aren't great regexes for email, but I wanted to test that my  regexes were being used before using a more complex one. While we're on the subject of helper sites though, I'd also mention: [regex powertoy](http://regex.powertoy.org/) and [regex info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue, this time when setting the email_regexp to a constant defined elsewhere. I reported it at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2233 with some failing/passing test case comparisons to try and nail it down.

Comment: Thanks for commenting Ben, but I've voted it down because by my understanding, you're *commenting*, not **answering**, and as such should have used the comment facility instead.